# How to edit multiple .xml files

Tags: xml, excel

I've got 205 XML files spread over 21 folders. These files contain translations for a piece of software we need to translate, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<translations>
<namespace id="modGridBatch">
    <string id="batch_grid_title">
        <translation lang="EN">Batch grid</translation>
        <translation lang="NL">Batch grid</translation>
    </string>
    <string id="batch_detail">
        <translation lang="EN">Batch details</translation>
        <translation lang="NL">Batch details</translation>
    </string>
</namespace>
</translations>
```

I need to add a 3rd language 'DE' which isn't the problem, I can macro it in the right place with notepad++.

The real problem is that the words will need to be translated by a professional translator and she doesn't know her way with XML files and will take too much time. I could use some VBA in excel to generate a list she could translate, but then exporting it back to the right XML files and folder is an issue.

So my question: is there any way I can import-export or edit (translator-proof) the XML files while keeping the structure intact?

Regards,
Dave

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It's a good question, but it's unlikely to generate good quality answers, because finding the right solution to this requirement requires a couple of weeks' consultancy not a few minutes typing.

Comment: There are existing formats for translations (see e.g. XLIFF) for which tooling already exists, and many translators are familiar with them. Why not use them instead?